# Rails Join not showing fields from related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

`Profile.joins(:course)` does not display the :course fields.

I have tried

```
Profile.joins(:course).select('profiles.*,courses.*')
```

and it appears in the select, but not the from command, so none of the course columns appear.

> Profile Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  courses.*,profiles.* FROM "profiles"
>   INNER JOIN "courses" ON "courses"."coursable_id" = "profiles"."id" AND
>   "courses"."coursable_type" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["coursable_type",
>   "Profile"], ["LIMIT", 11]]

```
@profile = Profile.joins(:course).select('profiles.*,courses.*')
@profile.department # a field on Courses table
```

> NoMethodError (undefined method `department' for  Profile::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007fb4f4955dc0>)

SOLUTION:

```
@profile.first.department # a field on Courses table
```

Comment: Add a code example showing how you are trying to get what you are expecting.

Answer (score 3):

`Select` only displays columns that exist on the model you called `select` on (i.e. Profile). But the attributes of `Course` is still available.

i.e. you can call them as you typically would:

```
@profile = Profile.joins(:course).select('profiles.*,courses.*')
@profile.course_name # if course_name is a field of course
```